# Facebook OpenGraph Places Category and Description

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was researching the Facebook OpenGraph and I was wondering if the FBGraphPlace inherits some sort of description field inherited from another object. I need some basic information about the venues I pull with the iOS Facebook SDK.

The code I tried was this: (venue is a FBGraphObject)

```
[venue objectForKey:@"description"];
```

but it returns a null string.

The second issue is that the venues' category returned by the open graph is almost always "Local Business", when on Facebook they have more specific categories, such as "Pizza Place" or "Restaurant". I'm accessing the category as such:

```
myString = venue.category;
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Hi there did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If I do, I'll definitely post a solution. I haven't worked with the SDK in a while so I checked it again just now and I didn't see anything different for FBGraphPlace.